# What parameter represents sigma in scikitleans Support Vector Machine?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to tune the Gaussian Width for a Support Vector Machine using a Radial Basis Function (RBF) Kernel.

I found that the Guassian Width is represented by Sigma in the RBF kernels equation. When looking at the documentation for SciKitLearns SVC (Support Vector CLassifier) I found no reference to sigma, only a reference to a Gamma parameter that acts as a "Free parameter" for RBF.

I was just wondering what parameter (if any) represents sigma as I have researched on several different sites and forum posts and I have found nothing.

Comment: Take a look at this [Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138549/correct-arguments-for-svm-function-in-r). From what I can tell from a [number of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281642/estimate-sigma-for-rbf-kernel-svm) I've found scattered about, `sigma = 1/gamma`.

Comment: Ok cheers, so the sigma is derived from the value you set as gamma?

Comment: I don't quite understand the distinction myself. I wish it were more clearly laid out somewhere, but that's all I could find, and why I'm not posting this as an answer. I hope at least I could give you some places to look.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Honestly really useful!

Comment: I'm late to the party, but to me it seems that the variance sigma^2 is 0.5, such that the nominator becomes 1. I back this up, I have a SVR model and I tried "manually" predicting the value for an input vector, i.e, I did not use the `model.predict()` attribute. In the manual prediction I did not use any value in the nominator, and got the correct result, even though my gamma is something like 0.0003. If you're interested I can share more detail (in fact, I wrote them in a SO post). If you got a better answer in the meantime, I'd like to know it!